# Adding buttons to a TabControl Tab in C#

Tags: c#, button, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl in a windows form. I have pragmaticly added new tabs like so:

```
for (int i = 1; i < numOfLanguages; i++)
{
     // add a tab for each language
     string tabTitle = split[i];
     TabPage newTab = new TabPage(tabTitle);
     languageTabs.TabPages.Add(newTab);
}
```

inside the loop I want to set up the other controlls for each tab. mainly I want to add buttons. I have seen this code:

```
tabPage1.Controls.Add(new Button());
```

Based off this example I want to do something similar like:

```
languageTabs.SelectTab(split[i]).Add(new Button());
```

I know that this code wont work. Have been looking through the params and cant see anything that lets me do this kind of thing.

Any ideas community?

Comment: SelectTab(split[i]) returns void, it doesn't return the current selectedTab

Comment: @MBen -- I realise this, hence why I added "this code doesnt work". I used SelectTab in my example as it closly resembeled a name that my code should be doing.

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectTab` moves the actual `TabControl` to the specified tab, it does not return the tab to let you manipulate it.

---

You can index into the tab pages as follows:

```
languageTabs.TabPages[2].Controls.Add(new Button());
```

If you have set the [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name.aspx) property on the `TabPage` on creation, then you can also find individual tabs by key:

```
for (int i = 1; i < numOfLanguages; i++)
{
     // add a tab for each language
     string tabTitle = split[i];
     TabPage newTab = new TabPage(tabTitle);
     newTab.Name = tabTitle;
     languageTabs.TabPages.Add(newTab);
}

...

languageTabs.TabPages[split[i]].Controls.Add(new Button());
```

([See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/839bz4e1.aspx) for more)

Whichever is most convenient.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ?

`languageTabs.TabPages.First(tab => tab.Title == split[i]).Add(new Button());`

This might be not reliable (crash) if your tabcontrol does not have tab with specific name, so you might want more reliable way:

```
if (languageTabs.TabPages.Exists(tab => tab.Title == split[i]))
{
    languageTabs.TabPages.First(tab => tab.Title == split[i]).Add(new Button());
}
```