# Access a DataGridView via a parent (TabControl) to set value -- C# form

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, tabcontrol

This question is related to one I asked earlier:

[Adding buttons to a TabControl Tab in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309188/adding-buttons-to-a-tabcontrol-tab-in-c-sharp)

In short: I have programmatically added controls to tabs in a c# form.

I would now like to access the tab's controls (in this case a DataGridView) and set some values.

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[1].Value = "General";
```

Above is how I have done it before, but I can't use this right now due to scope, so I need to access the DataGridView via the parent:

```
// THIS IS NON WORKING CODE NO COMMENTS ABOUT THE SYNTAX PLEASE
languageTabs.TabPages[0].Controls["grid"].Row[int].Cells[int].Value = "General";

// TabControl -> First Tab -> DataGridView -> the column -> row -> set value
```

Is there a way to do the same functionality of the first code snippet, but using the parents like in the second snippet?

---

EDIT:

Here is some more code if it helps:

```
 while ((line = stringReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //if the line isn't a comment (comments start with an '/')
                    if (line[0] != '/')
                    {
                        // split the string at each tab
                        string[] split = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' });

                        // is this line the "blah"?
                        if (split[0] == "blah")
                        {
                            // we now need to set up the tables to be used
                            for (int i = 1; i < split.Length; i++)
                            {
                                // add a tab for each language
                                string tabTitle = split[i];
                                newTab = new TabPage(tabTitle);
                                newTab.Name = tabTitle;
                                languageTabs.TabPages.Add(newTab);

                                // add a DataGridView to each tab
                                grid = new DataGridView();
                                grid.SetBounds(14, 68, 964, 420);
                                grid.Name = tabTitle + "Grid";

                                // set the columns in the DataGridView
                                stringIdColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                                stringIdColumn.HeaderText = "String ID";
                                stringIdColumn.Width = 75;
                                stringIdColumn.Name = tabTitle + "StringIDColumn";
                                grid.Columns.Insert(0, stringIdColumn);

...

...

// add the DataGridView and button to each tab
                                languageTabs.TabPages[split[i]].Controls.Add(grid);
    }
}
 else
                        {
                            // this isn't the identifier it must be the start of the languages
                            // load the strings to the tables
                            // THIS IS WHERE I WANT MY CODE
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it working:

```
Control[] ctrls = languageTabs.TabPages[1].Controls.Find("EnglishGrid", true);
                            if (ctrls[0] != null)
                            {
                                DataGridView dgv = ctrls[0] as DataGridView;
                                dgv.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value = 1;
                            }
```