# Adding buttons programmatically to a TabControl (TabPage)

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I read this topic [(Adding buttons to a TabControl Tab in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309188/adding-buttons-to-a-tabcontrol-tab-in-c-sharp) but I don't figure out why my code below add one button only to the tabpage.
I've obviously debugged that the foreach works properly.

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\quicklauncher.ini"))
{   
    TabPage page = new TabPage(foldername);
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(line);
    foreach (FileInfo file in d.GetFiles("*.*"))
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = file.Name;
        button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
        page.Controls.Add(button);
    }   
    tabControl.TabPages.Add(page); //add our tab page to the tab control
}
```

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

You thought it added only 1 button for you but in fact it did not, it added all the buttons for you but those buttons **had the same Location** (which is (0,0) by default). That's why you did think there was only 1 button (because you saw only 1 last button on top of others).

You added buttons **automatically** to your tabpage, so you should have some rule to locate them, I'm not sure what that rule is but I suppose you want to line them up vertically (just an example), I'm going to correct your code to achieve such a thing, at least you will see it work, and in fact all the buttons are added normally:

```
//you need some variable to save the next Top for each new button:
//let's call it nextTop:
int nextTop = 0;
foreach (FileInfo file in d.GetFiles("*.*"))
{
    Button button = new Button { Top = nextTop,      
                                 Text = file.Name };
    button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
    page.Controls.Add(button);
    nextTop += button.Height + 5; //it's up to you on the 
                                 //Height and vertical spacing
}
//...
```

You can also try using some layout control like `FlowLayoutPanel` and `TableLayoutPanel` to contain all the buttons, they can help arrange your buttons in some way you may want, just try it.